# Hosting service that use lighttpd

Tags: hosting, lighttpd

where can i find a list of good web hosting services that allow me to use lighttpd? (and wordpress, btw)

I know of dreamhost if you use the privete server, but the price is quite high isn't it? How good is as a service?

Thanks

Comment: why -1??? what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a VPS or dedicated server. These give you root access to the servers, so you can install your own web server.

VPS servers can cost as low as $5 a month depending on what you need. I would check out lowendbox.com. They have deals on very cheep VPS servers.